# MySQL Error 1064 (42000) Script Insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, insert-into

I receive an error for any insert statement I put after load data. I have tried rearranging the insert statements but still received errors. Not sure what to do, any help would be awesome!

The error is: `Error: "Error 1064 (42000): ...  right syntax to use near 
'--Load data 
Insert into Branches(Name,Adress,Phone)
Values('North','123 sout' at line 1`

The SQL is as follows:

```
Drop Database If exists HW2;
Create Database HW2;
use HW2

# Defining Tables 

CREATE TABLE Branches(
Name VARCHAR(30),
Address VARCHAR(45),
Phone Char(10),
PRIMARY KEY(Name));

Create Table Employees(
ID Char(10),
fName Varchar(10),
mName Varchar(10),
lName Varchar(10),
address Varchar(35),
ssn char(9),
phone char(10),
jobTitle Varchar(20),
salary varchar(6),
Primary Key(ID));

create table Members(
ID char(10),
fname varchar(20),
mName varchar(20),
lName varchar(20),
phone char(10),
address varchar(35),
birthday Date,
Primary Key(ID));

create table BooksCheckOut(
booksID Char(10),
membersID char(10) NOT NULL,
checkOutDate Date,
returnDate Date, 
costLate Varchar(5),
title varchar(20),
publishYr year(4),
location varchar(30),
status varchar(25),
category varchar(30),
publisher varchar(30),
costLoss varchar(5),
Primary Key(booksID),
foreign key(membersID) references Members(ID));

create table printBooks(
ID char(10), 
ISBN varchar(13),
Primary Key(ID),
Foreign Key(ID) References BooksCheckOut(booksID));

create table AudioBooks(
ID char(10),
ASI varchar(13),
narrator varchar(25),
listenLength varchar(5),
lang varchar(25),
Primary Key(ID),
Foreign Key(ID) References BooksCheckOut(booksID));

create table Authors(
ID char(10),
fName varchar(20),
mName varchar(20),
lName varchar(20),
Primary Key(ID));

create table writes(
aID char(10),
bcheckID char(10),
primary Key(aID,bcheckID),
foreign key (aID) references Authors(ID),
foreign key(bcheckID) references BooksCheckOut(booksID));


create table stores(
branchName varchar(30),
booksID char(10),
primary key(branchName, booksID),
foreign key(branchName) references Branches(name),
foreign key(booksID) references BooksCheckOut(booksID));


create table WorksAt(
empID char(10),
branchName varchar(30),
primary key(empID, branchName),
foreign key(empID) references Employees(ID),
foreign key(branchName) references Branches(name));

--Load data 

Insert into Branches(Name,Address,Phone) 
Values('North','123 south road California 90210','2332551234'),
('South','123 south road California 90210','2332551234'),
('West','123 south road California 90210','2332551234'),
('East','123 south road California 90210','2332551234'),
('NorthEast','123 south road California 90210','2332551234');

Insert Into Employees(ID,fName,mName,lName,address,ssn,phone,jobTitle,salary) 
Values('1234567891','John','Jane','Doe','8701 green street NC 27411','123456789','1123456789','SalesRep','65000'),
('1234567892','John','Jane','Doe','8701 green street NC 27411','123456789','1123456789','SalesRep','65000'),
('1234567893','John','Jane','Doe','8701 green street NC 27411','123456789','1123456789','SalesRep','65000'),
('1234567894','John','Jane','Doe','8701 green street NC 27411','123456789','1123456789','SalesRep','65000'),
('1234567895','John','Jane','Doe','8701 green street NC 27411','123456789','1123456789','SalesRep','65000');

Insert into Members(ID,fName,mName,lName,phone,address,birthday)
Values('9876543211','David', 'Thomas','Hoy','3211234561','3214 green road NC 25252','1995-04-21'),
('9876543212','David', 'Thomas','Hoy','3211234561','3214 green road NC 25252','1995-04-21'),
('9876543213','David', 'Thomas','Hoy','3211234561','3214 green road NC 25252','1995-04-21'),
('9876543214','David', 'Thomas','Hoy','3211234561','3214 green road NC 25252','1995-04-21'),
('9876543215','David', 'Thomas','Hoy','3211234561','3214 green road NC 25252','1995-04-21');

Insert into BooksCheckOut(booksID,membersID,checkOutDate,returnDate,costLate,title,publishYr,location,status,category,publisher,costLoss)
Values('1010101010', '9876543211','2009-04-13','2009-04-14','5.00','Catcher','2005','California','In Stock', 'Non-Fiction', 'Pearson','1.00'),
('1010101011', '9876543212','2009-04-13','2009-04-14','5.00','Catcher','2005','California','In Stock', 'Non-Fiction', 'Pearson','1.00'),
('1010101012', '9876543213','2009-04-13','2009-04-14','5.00','Catcher','2005','California','In Stock', 'Non-Fiction', 'Pearson','1.00'),
('1010101013', '9876543214','2009-04-13','2009-04-14','5.00','Catcher','2005','California','In Stock', 'Non-Fiction', 'Pearson','1.00'),
('1010101014', '9876543215','2009-04-13','2009-04-14','5.00','Catcher','2005','California','In Stock', 'Non-Fiction', 'Pearson','1.00');

Insert into printBooks(ID, ISBN) 
Values('1010101010','1234567891234'),
('1010101011','1234567891234'),
('1010101012','1234567891234'),
('1010101013','1234567891234'),
('1010101014','1234567891234');

Insert into AudioBooks(ID,ASI,narrator,listenLength,lang)
Values('1010101010','102013','Stephen King','5:00','English'),
('1010101011','102013','Stephen King','5:00','English'),
('1010101012','102013','Stephen King','5:00','English'),
('1010101013','102013','Stephen King','5:00','English'),
('1010101014','102013','Stephen King','5:00','English');


Insert into Authors(ID,fName,mName,lName)
Values('1020320101','Steve','Thomas','James'),
('1020320102', 'Steve','Thomas','James'),
('1020320103', 'Steve','Thomas','James'),
('1020320104', 'Steve','Thomas','James'),
('1020320105', 'Steve','Thomas','James');

Insert into stores(branchName,booksID)
Values('North','1010101010'),
('South','1010101011'),
('West','1010101012'),
('East','1010101013'),
('NorthEast','1010101014');

Insert into WorksAt(empID,branchName)
Values('1234567891','North'),
('1234567892','South'),
('1234567893','West'),
('1234567894','East'),
('1234567895','NorthEast');

Insert into writes(aID,bcheckID)
Values('1020320101','1010101010'),
('1020320102','1010101011'),
('1020320103','1010101012'),
('1020320104','1010101013'),
('1020320105','1010101014');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/comments.html) you must place whitespace or control character after the double dash "--".

> From a “-- ” sequence to the end of the line. This style is supported
>   as of MySQL 3.23.3. In MySQL, the “-- ” (double-dash) comment style
>   requires the second dash to be followed by at least one whitespace or
>   control character (such as a space, tab, newline, and so on). This
>   syntax differs slightly from standard SQL comment syntax, as discussed
>   in Section 1.9.5.8, “'--' as the Start of a Comment”.

New code:

```
-- Load Data
```